# How can I solve a problem with caesar code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, caesar-cipher

I am trying to create a simple Caesar Code function that has to decipher a string given in input.

> Clear text =   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> Encrypted= D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A B C

This is my code to DECIPHER:

```
def deciph(s):
    b='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    a='defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc'
    for i in s:
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if i==a[j]:
                s=s.replace(i,b[j])
    return s
```

This code works almost always fine, for example:

```
deciph('vxq') --> 'sun'

deciph('ohwwhu') --> 'letter'
```

The problems are those of this case:

```
deciph('sp')--> 'mm'  #should be 'pm'

deciph('ol')-->'ii'  #should be 'li'
```

and so when, tha first letter, deciphered, is equal to the second letter encrypted.

How can I modify my code? where is the mistake? I know that on internet there are many other ways to do the same exercise, but now I am interested to understand the mistake of MY code.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use your example of `deciph('sp')`. The problem is when you do `s=s.replace(i,b[j])`, you are initally replacing all instances of `'s'` with `'p'`, giving you `s = 'pp'`, and then  on the second pass, replacing all instances of `'p'` with `'m'`, giving you `s = 'mm'`. This could be rectified by holding a new initial variable `rv = ''`, and then using `rv+=b[j]` for each letter instead of altering `s`. Then at the end, just return `rv`.

Comment: I tried a version similar but in this case, the new string rv does not mantain spaces between words

Answer (score 2):

As already mentionned, the issue you observe is due to inconditionnaly replacing each char in `s` by the "clear" one - since `a` and `b` are composed of the same letters and `str.replace(x, y)` replaces ALL occurences of `x` with `y`, some of the chars are "deciphered" again and again...

The first step toward a proper solution is to build a new string manually instead of using `str.replace`:

```
def decipher(s):    
    result = []
    for char in s:
        for index, crypted in enumerate(a):
            if char == crypted:
                result.append(b[index])
                # no need to go further
                break
        else:
            # The else clause of a for loop is only executed
            # if the for loop runs to the end without being
            # interrupted by a break statement.
            #
            # Here we use it to handle the case of whitespaces 
            # or any other char that's in `s` but not in `a` 

            result.append(c)

    return "".join(result)
```

Now while this will yield the expected results, it's uselessly complicated and very inefficient. What you're doing is, essentially, [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)) - in this case, mapping encrypted characters to decrypted one -, so the obvious solution here is to use [Python's main `mapping` builtin type](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping): a `dict`:

```
CLEAR = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
CRYPT = 'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc'

DECIPHER_MAP = dict(zip(CRYPT, CLEAR))

def decipher(s):
    ## the 'unrolled' version:
    # result = []
    # for c in s:
    #     result.append(DECIPHER_MAP.get(c, c))
    # return "".join(result)

    # which is even simpler _and_ faster (and uses less memory)
    # using a generator expression.

    return "".join(DECIPHER_MAP.get(c, c) for c in s)
```

As you can see, the algorithm is *much* simpler. It's also much faster (a dict lookup is 0(1) and highly optimized), and eats less memory (no ned for the intermediate `result` list).

In programming, choosing the proper data structure is key...

NB:

> now I am interested to understand the mistake of MY code.

This is very laudable, to say the least - I whish everyone here would do the same. Now that's something you could have sorted out by yourself with the most simple and basic debugging technic: tracing code execution by printing out your current state at strategic moments:

```
def deciph(s):    
    for i in s:
        print("i : '{}' - s : '{}'".format(i, s))
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if i==a[j]:
                print("i == '{}' - replacing with '{}'".format(i, b[j]))
                s = s.replace(i, b[j])
                print("now s : '{}'".format(s))   
    return s


>>> deciph("pme")
i : 'p' - s : 'pme'
i == 'p' - replacing with 'm'
now s : 'mme'
i : 'm' - s : 'mme'
i == 'm' - replacing with 'j'
now s : 'jje'
i : 'e' - s : 'jje'
i == 'e' - replacing with 'b'
now s : 'jjb'
'jjb'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-find-python/) method to find the position of characters in a loop.

```
def deciph(s):
    b='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    a='defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc'
    decrypted = ''
    for i in s:
       pos = a.find(i)
       if pos != -1:
         decrypted += b[pos]
       else:
          pass # Here you can throw an error
          # Or you can directly pass it to the decrypted string
          # since you want spaces and other punctuation to remain
          # decrypted += i
    return decrypted
```

Comment: Technically correct, but still uselessly complicated, and quite inefficient...